# Grails - mapping a many-to-many parents/children relation to a single join table

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, nhibernate-mapping, grails-orm

My question is based on the following (simplified) Grails domain class

```
class Dimension {

    String name

    static hasMany = [
        children: Dimension,
        parents: Dimension
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to map the many-to-many parents/children relationship to a single join table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do that is to **create another domain class** that represents a parent-child relationship.

```
class DimensionDependency {
  Dimension parent
  Dimension child

  static belongsTo = Dimension
}

class Dimension {
  static hasMany = [parentDependencies: DimensionDependency]
  static mappedBy = [parentDependencies: 'child']
  static mapping = { parentDependencies cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' }
}
```

The `mappedBy` keywords specifies that the object refering to a `DimensionDependency` is always the child. By specifying `all-delete-orphan` in the mapping, we make sure that when removing a `parentDependency` from a child, the associated `DimensionDependency` is deleted from the database.

You may also add convenience methods to your `Dimension` class to encapsulate operations on `DimensionDependencies`, to make the interface more GORM-like.

```
  static transients = ['children', 'parents']

  Set<Dimension> getChildren()
  {
    AssignmentDependency.findAllByParent(this).child
  }

  Set<Dimension> getParents()
  { 
    parentDependencies?.parent ?: []
  }

  Dimension addToParents(Dimension parent)
  {
    if (!parentDependencies.find { it.parent == parent && it.child == this })
    {
      addToParentDependencies(new DimensionDependency(parent: parent, child: this))
    }
    return this
  }

  Dimension removeFromParents(Dimension parent)
  {
    def dep = parentDependencies.find { it.parent == parent }
    removeFromParentDependencies(dep)
    dep.delete(flush: true)
    return this
  }
```

I've been using this approach for some time and have had no trouble so far.